# Samsung np530-0u3c-a02gr cannot install Windows

Tags: windows-7

I am struggling to install Windows in this machine, I tried to search Google and I applied various fixes but none worked.

What i did was

1. USB install Windows 7

   The USB is found, I installed Windows (first boot) and then it restarts. When it does and i unplug the USB, the harddisk is not loading anything.
2. recovery

   Again, the system recovers and it tells that it needs to reboot. When it does, nothing is loaded and my only option is to recover again.

To me it seems that for some reason when the files are copied to the harddisk but something is missing and the HDD does not get marked as bootable.

I tried to install with UEFI and with secure boot and without, almost everything I could imagine - I really don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 2):

Because i spent some days trying everything i have to post here that using an external dvd did the trick.I cannot tell that its the only way but it will save you time.With the dvd i got no reboot loops, normal install.